# environment variable in ant that persists into runtime

Tags: ant

Is it possible to set an environment variable in ant that persists into runtime?
I've tried  
in the build.xml.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to execute an external command and want to modify the environment, use the env tag.  The same tag exists for the java and junit tags.

```
<exec executable="cmd">
    <env key="variable" value="info" />
</exec>
```

See the [ant env specification](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html#env) for more information.

For any other tags, you will have to pass in the variable as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables belong to processes, not executables.  Compilation happens in a different process than running.  So unless ant is being used to actually run the program, ant cannot affect the run time environment.

That said, you can certainly set things up so that, for instance, certain variables get written by ant to a configuration file, and then at run-time the Java process will read that configuration file.  So what you want to do can be done.  But not through environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the environment variable to .gnomerc (I'm using ubuntu), and everything works just fine.